# Event Organiser date in loop

Tags: wordpress, loops, events

I am using WordPress in combination with WP Events Organiser. On my index.php, I want to display events and posts in the same loop, but only categories of "startseite" should be displayed either for the events as well as for the posts. At the moment it is working like this:

```
<?php global $wp_query;
$args = array(
'post_type' => array('post','event'),

'tax_query' => array(
'relation' => 'OR',
array(
'taxonomy' => 'category',
'terms' => 'startseite',
'field' => 'slug'
),
array(
'taxonomy' => 'event-category',
'terms' => 'startseite',
'field' => 'slug'),
));
query_posts( $args ); ?>


<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

... further on the loop:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <article class="d-1of3" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'cf' ); ?> role="article">
        <div class="entry-content">
            <h2 class="h2 entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <p class="byline entry-meta vcard">
              <?php printf( __( '', 'bonestheme' ).' %1$s',
              '<time class="updated entry-time" datetime="' . get_the_time('Y-m-d') . '" itemprop="datePublished">' . get_the_time(get_option('date_format')) . '</time>'                            
              ); ?>
            </p>
            <section class="cf">
                <?php the_content(); ?>

                <?php echo eo_get_the_start('jS M YY'); ?>
            </section>
        </div>

        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large' ); ?> 

    </article>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Now I would like to display the date of the Event. I have found the following link with an example: http://codex.wp-event-organiser.com/function-eo_get_events.html

But I can't figure out how to change my code just to display the date. AND also it would be great to order the events by the date. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Hi, so you need to show the date of the event or show a list of events in a certain date?

Comment: Hi, I would like to show all events of a certain category (which I could figure out). Now I want to display the date on each event, when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

just check the documentation [in here](http://codex.wp-event-organiser.com/function-eo_get_the_start.html).

Basically you add this:

```
echo eo_get_the_start('jS M YY');
```

Where you need to show the date.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - but it didn't help... See above, I have edited the whole code.